# java shell command to sort csv file

Tags: java, shell, unix, csv

i need to sort a csv file by the first column, which is a timestamp. I've been trying to do this with the following code, but the inputstream of the process p is always just blank:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sort -k1,1 -t, Bucket_Stats.csv");
    p.waitFor();
    // read this file into InputStream
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Sorted_Bucket_Stats.csv");
    System.out.println(IOUtils.copy(in,output));
    output.flush();
    output.close();
```

Comment: why don't you use the `-o` flag of the `sort` command?

Comment: you are a saint. make this an answer so i can thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of handling the output in Java, you can use the

`-o` or `--output=FILE`

flag of the `sort` command and pass a filename for the output.

If you pass the same filename as the input, it will be overwritten.